# Implementing a horizontal UIPanGestureRecognizer within a vertical UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I know this topic has been discussed at length but I can't find any proper solutions to my problem despite searching.

I'm essentially trying to replicate the behaviour you experience in Mail.app's table view in a scroll view. I want the user to be able to scroll through a view of content as normal, but also be able to swipe items out of the view.

I have a standard `UIScrollView`, which only scrolls vertically. I then have several views which have `UIPanGestureRecognizer`s attached to them. My view controller is the delegate for these gesture recognizers, to ensure normal scrolling of my scroll view.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]] && gestureRecognizer != self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer) return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

The issue is that these gesture recognizers always recognize when the user begins scrolling the scroll view. I understand why this is happening, and I've tried dozens of ways to try work around it.

The biggest frustration of mine is that `UIScrollView`'s gesture recognizer never fails. If it did, I could make my other gesture recognizers require it to fail before recognizing.

The last option I've settled with (which sort of works), is basically best described as:

1. The pan recognizer begins
2. I record the point of the touch
3. Every time the recognizer changes, I check to ensure the points are all along a (nearly) perfect horizontal line.
4. If there are more than 5 sequential points that validate, I continue to treat the recognizer as normal and disable scrolling in my scroll view.

Is this the best/only way to do this?